# Rails partial from different controller in a Bootstrap tab

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a `Home` page with 2 Bootstap tabs.  I'm having problems with the 2nd tab.  I'm trying to render a list of workorders.  For that list I'm using dataTables and ajax.

My issue is that workorders/index7.html.erb works fine as a stand alone page. But, I want to use it in a Bootstrap tab on the Home page.

For all my other Bootstrap tab lists, I'm using partials from within the same controller.  But, in this case, I need to use a view from the `Workorder` controller not the `Home` controller.

This is the code I'm trying in the `Home` view:

```
<div class="tab-pane" id="tab2">
  <%= render "workorders/index7" %>
</div>
```

That code gives me:

```
Missing partial workorders/index7
```

WHY?  If I change the file name to _index7.html.erb the code won't execute to get the json.

But, because it's a partial, starting with `_`, the connection to the Workorder controller code for `index7` doesn't work.  I also tried `_index7` in the Workorder controller.

The `Workorder` controller has this code:

```
 def index7
   @workorders = Workorder.all

 respond_to do |format|
   format.html # index.html.erb
   format.json { render json: Workorders3Datatable.new(view_context) }
 end
end
```

That code uses a file called `workorders3_datatable.rb` to get the data via ajax and format it for dataTables.

QUESTIONS:

1) Do I have to use a partial in the `Home` tab? Or is there a way to render a file called workorders/index7.html.erb in the tab?

2) Why does index7.html.erb use the controller code for index7, yet the partial _index7.html.erb won't use code if I call it _index7 in the controller?

3) I read this "Render will just render the view, it won't run the action associated with it." - is that true?

Thanks for your help - I know this is confusing.

Reddirt

UPDATE 1

The view runs great as workorders/index7 - but, if I change it to a partial and put it in a tab = workorders/_index7 - the controller code for index7 doesn't seem to execute.

Comment: Does your _index7.html.erb use any instance variables?  If yes, have they been defined in your Home controller on the action that renders the tabs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**1) Do I have to use a partial in the Home tab? Or is there a way to view a file called workorders/index7.html in the tab?**

If you want to follow this approach.  From Home controller pass the collection (`@workorders = Workorder.all`)

Then in the home view pass it to the `workorders/index7` as locals

```
<div class="tab-pane" id="tab2">
  <%= render "workorders/index7" locals: {workorders: @workorders} %>
</div>
```

This will make it available to `workorders/index7` do remember to change the variable to a local variable `workorders`.

Comment: The same view `index7` if it's not a partial (used in a bootstrap tab), uses the workorders controller to get the json via the workorders3.datatable.rb - this is the line in the workorders controller `format.json { render json: Workorders3Datatable.new(view_context) }`. The workorders3_datatable.rb starts with `class Workorders3Datatable`.

Comment: My issue is that workorders/index7.html.erb works fine as a stand alone page.  But, I want to use it in a Bootstrap tab on the Home page.

Answer (score 0):

You need to include `:partial` in the view for your Home page:

```
<%= render :partial => "workorders/index7" %>
```

The `app/views/workorders` folder will need a file called `_index7.html.erb`. To accomplish this from your current setup, you can move the contents of `index7.html.erb` into this partial, and then use:

```
<%= render :partial => "index7" %>
```

in the original `index7.html.erb`. That way you can render that as a whole page and within your Home page as a partial.

Comment: The view file is `workorders/index7.html.erb`. I tried that also.

Comment: Do you have a folder called `app/views/workorders`? And a file in there called `_index7.html.erb`?

Comment: The file doesn't start with _

Comment: Ah, you need to use the `_` underscore to specify a partial.

Comment: That's because I tried to change the name to start with _.  But, the json controller code for index7 didn't execute.

Comment: How would I get the controller code `  def index7` to execute for the partial?

Comment: So, if you want to access the `@workorders` variable from Home, you have to initiate it there as well using `@workorders = Workorder.all`. Calling one controller action from another is a bad practice.